# error with libgmail python

Tags: python, sms, libgmail

Hi guys I am running the following python script to send an sms via the libgmail module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import libgmail

stuff = libgmail.GmailAccount("example@gmail.com", "password")
myCellEmail = "phonenumber@tmomail.net"

stuff.login()
msg=libgmail.GmailComposedMessage(myCellEmail, "", "Hello World! From python-libgmail!")
stuff.sendMessage(msg)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sms.py", line 7, in <module>
    stuff.login()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libgmail.py", line 305, in login
    pageData = self._retrievePage(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libgmail.py", line 340, in _retrievePage
    req = ClientCookie.Request(urlOrRequest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_request.py", line 31, in __init__
    if not _rfc3986.is_clean_uri(url):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_rfc3986.py", line 62, in is_clean_uri
    return not bool(BAD_URI_CHARS_RE.search(uri))
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

the libgmail module has been installed in my desired directory, so that isn't the problem. any answers will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgmail is no longer maintained. (I was its last maintainer.)

However, now that Gmail has an IMAP interface, you don't even really need libgmail any more. Python's [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) will let you check your mail, and [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) will let you send it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known bug, and won't be fixed obviously, cf 
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3149613&group_id=113492&atid=665330

I guess you'll either have to find another solution or take maintainance of libgmail.

Comment: that's a shame, I guess I will have to take another route.